# Provide __repr__ for function object

Tags: python, repr

When you define a function like so:

```
def f():
    """Does something."""
    return None
```

and you print it:

```
print(f)
```

You get a pretty uninformative description like "function at 0xwhatever".

I know you could just

```
print(f.func_name)  # python 2
print(f.__name__)  # python 3
```

But is there a way to provide a __repr__ for a function, just in case I ever wanted to?

Comment: Are you looking for `help(f)`?